# Publish CLI tool on Microsoft Store

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, publish

I'm planning to publish an open source CLI tool. One good option seems to publish it in the official Store.

However while checking the docs it seems to be required that the files are signed. Not very easy if you want to publish a jar and a bat file.

I can sign the jar, but I don't think that this accepted since I don't plan to buy a code signing certificate.

Has someone experienced with the publishing process of the Windows Store and like to share it?